# How to give the path for TARGETDIR and SourceDir in wix?

Tags: java, wix

I am new for WIX installer setup creating. I am doing standalone java project. So i want to know how to give path directory for Id and Name.When i give path it gives error.

> Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'
>
> Error  3   The Directory/@Id attribute's value, 'Program Files\CEB', is not a legal identifier.  Identifiers may contain ASCII characters A-Z, a-z, digits, underscores (_), or periods (.).  Every identifier must begin with either a letter or an underscore.   C:\Users\User\Desktop\SetupProject1\SetupProject1\Product.wxs   32  1   SetupProject1

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps the directory structure xml code would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have listed show that you have an invalid ID. It looks like your ID is set to 'Program Files\CEB'. In Wix this is not valid as the slash is not acceptable. The error then goes on explaining what is acceptable. Which is:

- ASCII Characters (A-Z or a-z)
- Digits (0-9)
- Underscores (_)
- Periods (.)

To fix this problem you may just want to change your id to have the value 'Program_Files_CEB'. This will get you past the error.

Is there something specific you are trying to achieve by having the path in the ID tag? If not, then this suggestion should be good. If you are trying to help direct where the file will be installed to, then you need to look into using [directory](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/directory.html) elements.